# Angular 4 -> REST API Authentication using Self-Signed Certificate

Tags: angular, rest, angular4-httpclient

The back-end Java REST API is using self signed certificate for API authentication, so that only authorized API calls can invoke the REST API.

Assuming the server side is ready and client certificate is also produced, **is there a way for Angular 4 web front end to pick up my certificate when calling the API?**

Did not find any mention on [Angular Doc](https://angular.io/guide/http#httpclient)

My current Angular code (not using any authentication yet):

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private _http: HttpClient){}

getData(){
    return this._http.get(url);
  }

getResult(){
    this.myService.getData().subscribe(data => {
      //blah blah
    }, error => {
      //blah blah
    }) 
  }
```